# Necesito que el VSC me cargue las carpetas cuando voy escribiendo en el use de un archivo

Tags: vscode

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

aqui cuando voy escribiendo el nombre de las carpetas no me las autocompleta automaticamente, tengo que escribirlas a memoria

Comment: ¿Y eso es en qué lenguaje? Porque dependiendo del lenguaje habrá un plugin para el `autocomplete` al usar la sentencia `use`. Por favor sé más específico. Saludos

Comment: El lenguaje es PHP para se mas especifico es trabajando con el framework Laravel, en otro IDE yo escribo el nombre de la clase y el solo me da sugerencias de la ruta donde se encuentra para anadirlo en el use del archivo, aqui no sucede asi

Comment: Encontre uno que se llama Path Autocomplete. Gracias Mauricio